# PHP rewrite rule is not working for query string

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am writing the following rules in htaccess file to change the query string as directory structure

```
 RewriteRule ^dashboard/([0-9]*)?$ dashboard.php?user_id=$1
```

is used to rewrite the url. It is working fine on

```
localhost/project/dashboard // (dashboard.php)
```

and all links are as

```
localhost/project/css/style.css
localhost/project/js/script.js
```

But When I append an id

```
localhost/project/dashboard/1 // (dashboard.php?user_id=1)
```

It changes all the links as

```
localhost/project/dashboard/css/style.css
localhost/project/dashboard/js/script.js
```

Why it is appending the `dashboard` to all links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the style.css referenced in your html file?

If you have it like this href="css/style.css", the HTML doesn't know you're rewriting, thinks /1 is a folder and will look in dashboard/css/style.css

Any system that uses url rewrite usually has to write all the path to the styles and scripts to avoid this. so you will have to reference your style like this
href="http://localhost/project/css/style.css"

if you have a production and development environment it will help you to have a variable like

```
if($SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='localhost'){
  $BASE_URL = "http://localhost/project/"
}else{
  $BASE_URL = "http://mydomain.com/"
}
```

and put that before any call to css, scripts or images 
;)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you "tell him" to do that.

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([0-9]*)?$ dashboard.php?user_id=$1
         //  ^here you tell him to print that "dashboard"
```

Of course other links works - you don't even match them with that rule.

I found you something [here](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html), scroll down to the title "Strip Query Strings". There, it say you to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} example=
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1? [R=301]
```

Just, of course, change that url to your own.